# Tipi Shelter Formula

Tags: geometry

Autumn is quickly approaching in my neck of the woods and with it brings the start of camping and backpacking season. This year I want to work on my bushcraft skills with one particular project in mind: building a tipi shelter.

I suppose I could just start building one, hoping it turns out the right size and shape to accommodate a certain number of occupants. But the engineer in me wants to first see if math can help me out and save me some time and natural resources.

Basically, I am trying to come up with a plug-n-play style formula that can be used to build a tipi. For example, I foresee a few variables that the formula would use:

- **occupants**: the number of people laying down in the tipi
- **occupant height**: the average height of one occupant, in inches
- **fireplace size**: diameter, in inches, located at the center of the tipi
- **slant**: whatever is optimal, 45 degrees?

Here is a diagram I created that illustrates how the occupants will be laying down:

[image]

I would like the ability to simply plug in my numbers to each variable and have the formula return the following variables:

- **tipi diameter**: the diameter of the tipi
- **pole length**: the length of the vertical poles
- **number of structural poles**: traditionally, this is the core tri-pod, but maybe 4, 5, or 6 poles is better?
- **fireplace diameter**: the diameter of the fireplace
- **whatever else is useful**

My hat goes off to anyone who can figure that out :) I admire your skills and would feel very grateful for your help.

Comment: A few non-mathematical considerations from experience: Tipi poles can be bulky and heavy (believe me - you want as skinny poles as you can get away with, and no longer than necessary). And 45 degrees is not good. You want to be able to stand up, plus have good pull on the smoke. 60 degrees is probably about right. Usually the back is steeper than the front, so it isn't a perpendicular cone.